# Ansible makes a circular symlink during rails deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ansible, symlink

I'm using dresden-weekly (https://github.com/dresden-weekly/ansible-rails) ansible tasks to deploy my rails app, and a task in my playbook looks like this:

```
- name: Link production database
  file:
    src: "{{ RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH }}/db/production.sqlite3"
    path: "{{ RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH }}/db/production.sqlite3"
    state: link
    force: yes
    follow: false

- debug:
    msg: "RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH is {{ RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH }} & RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH {{ RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH }}"
```

But the symlink it makes points to *itself*:

```
deploy@scrappy:~/ansible_deploy/shared/db$ ls -l production.sqlite3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 deploy deploy 56 Sep  1 17:46 production.sqlite3 -> /home/deploy/ansible_deploy/shared/db/production.sqlite3
```

According to the debug info, the variables are correct:

```
TASK [rails/create-release : Link production database] *****************************************************************************************************
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.9.6/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netaddr/strategy/__init__.py:189: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if word_sep is not '':
ok: [scrappy]

TASK [rails/create-release : debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
/usr/local/Cellar/ansible/2.9.6/libexec/lib/python3.8/site-packages/netaddr/strategy/__init__.py:189: SyntaxWarning: "is not" with a literal. Did you mean "!="?
  if word_sep is not '':
ok: [scrappy] => {
    "msg": "RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH is /home/deploy/ansible_deploy/shared & RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH /home/deploy/ansible_deploy/releases/20200901174921"
}
```

Any clues as to the problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Works for me as expected in Ubuntu 20.04. Quoting from parameter [src](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#parameter-src)

> *"Path of the file to link to ... Unix command ln -s SRC DEST"*

Given the tree

```sh
shell> tree /home/deploy/ansible_deploy
/home/deploy/ansible_deploy
├── releases
│   └── 20200901174921
│       └── db
└── shared
    └── db
        └── production.sqlite3

5 directories, 1 file
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH: /home/deploy/ansible_deploy/shared
    RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH: /home/deploy/ansible_deploy/releases/20200901174921
  tasks:
    - name: Link production database
      file:
        src: "{{ RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH }}/db/production.sqlite3"
        path: "{{ RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH }}/db/production.sqlite3"
        state: link
        force: true
        follow: false
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH [{{ RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH }}]"
          - "RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH [{{ RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH }}]"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ****

TASK [Link production database] ****
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "RAILS_APP_SHARED_PATH [/home/deploy/ansible_deploy/shared]",
        "RAILS_APP_RELEASE_PATH [/home/deploy/ansible_deploy/releases/20200901174921]"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ****
localhost: ok=2 changed=1 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

```sh
shell> tree /home/deploy/ansible_deploy
/home/deploy/ansible_deploy
├── releases
│   └── 20200901174921
│       └── db
│           └── production.sqlite3 -> /home/deploy/ansible_deploy/shared/db/production.sqlite3
└── shared
    └── db
        └── production.sqlite3

5 directories, 2 files
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only fix I found was to make the action into a separate task and hard-code the paths instead of using a variable.